# IOS Why can't I drag connections from Storyboard elements to their respective ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ibaction, iboutlet

I'm revising my app so that the first scene is a Standard ViewController containing a UITableView and a UIButton. This replaces the original UITableViewController.

Problem is, I can't (Control or Right-Click) drag from these elements to set outlets or actions in the associated ViewController class file.

I've checked and rechecked to be sure the identity of the VC is correctly set to the appropriate VC custom class file, but still no success.

I wonder if it may have to do with the fact that I deleted (trashed) the original UITableViewController and class files, although the .h file continued to show up in the Custom Class list under the Identity section for a while. It appears to be gone now.

I've cleaned and rebuilt several times, and quit and restarted Xcode, but without success.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Thanks!

**Edit: Pursuant to a response to a similar question on SO, I checked the name of the ViewController class file by looking at the Storyboard as Source Code. The ViewController is in fact named correctly.**

Comment: Can you hook up the elements by selecting the specific view, open the Connections inspector and create the link from there?

Comment: @danielM--Yes, I can, but this doesn't have the desired effect of writing the IBOutlet of IBAction code, as it does when dragging from Storyboard to class file.

Comment: It turns out that a bunch of stuff got broken when I ripped out the original tableViewController and replaced it with a ViewController. The fix was to go back in and rewire a lot of connections by hand. Got it done, and would have put this info into an answer to save some helpful people the trouble of answering, but have to wait 2 days to answer, according to the rules. Thanks!